# Serialize class that inherits dictionary is not serializing properties

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

I have a class that inherits from Dictionary and has a couple of properties on it.  When I serialize it only serializes the dictionary and not the properties.  If I have a payload that includes the properties it does deserialize to them.  How can I make it serialize my object including the properties?

```
public class Maintenance : Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString); //Populates PersonId and all other properties end up in the dictionary.
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(maintenance); //Only returns dictionary contents
```

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to make serialization use the same behavior as deserialization seems to use.

Comment: That might not be the best way to do it.  I cant get intellisense to see the class properties, though they are there.  If the class implements a Dictionary as a property though (ie as a collection class), it works fine.

Comment: The intellisense works fine for me, and I can't use the dictionary as a property because I don't have control over the structure of the json payload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Json.Net documentation:
"Note that only the dictionary name/values will be written to the JSON object when serializing, and properties on the JSON object will be added to the dictionary's name/values when deserializing. Additional members on the .NET dictionary are ignored during serialization."

Taken from this link: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm

Assuming you want the keys & values of the dictionary on the same hierarchy level as PersonId in the json output, you can use the `JsonExtensionData` attribute with composition instead of inheritance, like this:

```
public class Maintenance
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> ThisNameWillNotBeInTheJson { get; set; }
}
```

Also look at this question: [How to serialize a Dictionary as part of its parent object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/json-net-serialize-dictionary-as-part-of-parent-object)