# Serialization when inheriting from Dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net, javascriptserializer

I'm using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize / deserialize a class that extends Dictionary.

The problem is, my custom properties are not being serialized. Here is my class:

```
public class Test : Dictionary<string, object> {
    public ushort Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my code:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var test = new Test {
    Id = 123,
    Name = "test"
};

var json = jss.Serialize(test);
```

The result in `json` is an empty json `{}`

I do not want to depend on Newtonsoft or JSON.Net or any other library.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I just noticed some, hm, peculiarities, when using both `dynamic` and `object`:

- `JavaScriptSerializer` defaults any number value to `int`.
- Also, `Newtonsoft` defaults any number to `long`.

That can cause casting exceptions in a class using property indexer (as suggested in the accepted answer), for example:

```
public class Test : Dictionary<string, dynamic> {
    public ushort Id { get => this[nameof(Id)]; set => this[nameof(Id)] = value; }
}
```

The `Id` property getter will try to implicitly convert `int` to `ushort`, which will fail.

**ADDITIONAL INFO 2**

I just found out so many weird behaviors with Newtonsoft:

I added these attributes to solve the 'long to ushort' problem:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test : Dictionary<string, dynamic> {
    [JsonProperty]
    public ushort Id { get => this[nameof(Id)]; set => this[nameof(Id)] = value; }
}
```

The above works! But when the property is a reference type:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test : Dictionary<string, dynamic> {
    [JsonProperty]
    public ushort Id { get => this[nameof(Id)]; set => this[nameof(Id)] = value; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Test Child { get => this[nameof(Child)]; set => this[nameof(Child)] = value; }
}
```

It tries to get the property before serializing it, resulting in a 'key not found exception'. I can't see why it tries to get the property only when it's a reference type, seems like a bug to me...

So you have to do something like this:

```
public Test Child { get => this.ContainsKey(index) ? this[nameof(Child)] : null; ... }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099396/serialize-class-that-inherits-dictionary-is-not-serializing-properties

Comment: You might want to consider using composition instead of inheritance. (Have a dictionary property instead)

Comment: Short of re-implementing most of JavaScriptObjectDeserializer (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web.extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,2f8d1f9fbf43dbfa), not sure you can. MSDN docs suggest using JSON.NET instead of this approach. Only [IgnoreJson] is supported (no [JsonProperty] or anything available)

Comment: Even [JavaScriptSerializer's API docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) recommends just using JSON.Net. But, looking around at the docs, you may need to implement your own `JavaScriptConverter` as there doesn't appear to be an inverse of the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments:

- MSDN recommends using JSON.NET even on JavaScriptSerializer's own docs
- Composition will allow you to use JavaScriptSerializer in this case (instead of inheritance)
- To work with existing data structure (inheritance), you would have to implement your own version of JavaScriptObjectDeserializer (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web.extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,2f8d1f9fbf43dbfa)
- The default serializer only supports attribute to ignore attribute (not include/rename)

To use composition, you would just need to modify your test object like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public ushort Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Items { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object> {};
}
```

Then the following code would work fine:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var test = new Test
{
    Id = 123,
    Name = "test",
};
test.Items.Add("A", 1);
var json = jss.Serialize(test);
```

The output would just be:

> {"Id":123,"Name":"test","Items":{"A":1}}

**UPDATE: Property Indexer**

You could add a default indexer to your class so that the following code would work:

```
test["A"] = 1;
var result = test["A"];
```

Here is the code to add for the default indexer:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get { return this.Items[key]; }
    set { this.Items[key] = value; }
}
```

You could extend this into implementing IDictionary I suppose, but I imagine just working with the composition should be easiest.

Comment: Oddly enough, JavaScriptSrializer defaults any number to int, and Newtonsoft defaults any number to long. That can mess up something like that property indexer. I've updated my question.